# How to Remove Resume Pic from Google Results

Tags: seo, google-analytics, analytics, links, wix

I created an online portfolio in Wix and created SEO optimization in Google Analytics. A pdf of my resume with personal info was part of the site as a link, and now its image is showing up in google results.  I went into Wix and set the page to private and actually removed the pdf from the files, but it is still showing up.

Any advice on how to get it out of the search results?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does setting a page private do? After this setting, will the page return a 404 when requested?

Comment: "created SEO optimization in Google Analytics" - What do you mean by this? GA is a visitor reporting tool, it doesn't do "SEO optimization"? "its image is showing up in google results" - An actual _image_ of the PDF content? Or something else? What generated that image? Where exactly does that appear in the search results?

Comment: @Kannan Yes, that is exactly what happens.

Comment: In that case, Jake's answer should help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that setting the URL of your PDF to "private" means that URL now returns 404 "not found", then your PDF should eventually leave search results, but this could take a little while.

If you want to go ahead and get it out of the results you should use Google Search Console, and request removal. Instructions here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846/removals-tool

Note that this is a "temporary removal" which gets the URL out of Google search results for about six months. So if the page is still live, then it will return to the search results in about six months.

If you want the page to be accessible, but don't want it to be indexed in search results, then you can use the robots.txt file block search engine crawlers from accessing it.

Comment: "use the robots.txt file" - Although I'm not sure that it is [possible to edit your `robots.txt` file on Wix](https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/robots-txt-please-help)? However, there is a [Wix help article describing how to edit your `robots.txt` file](https://support.wix.com/en/article/editing-your-sites-robotstxt-file), so maybe this feature is available to higher price plans?

Comment: That's awesome advice, thank you!